# render rest api response (javascript as text)

Tags: javascript

Please find the details.

1. Rest API call from javascript
2. Response is coming as string (which is javascript content)
3. How we can render the response as javascript which will be used in the html page.

Let me know,if any solutions for #3.

Comment: In #3 is the question how to respond with patched javascript content from the server side, or how to treat the received response as a script on the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of parsing Javascript from a raw string, the correct way would just be to create a script tag. Parsing Javascript manually is generally considered dangerous and bad practice, but I'll show you both ways.

#### Proper way:

Assumes the URL doesn't require any processing. If it does, you probably shouldn't use it anyway.

```js
function addJavascript(script_url){
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  document.body.appendChild(script);
  script.setAttribute('src', script_url);
}
```

#### Terrible, very bad, dangerous way:

For completeness, don't actually do this. Check out the big red warning on top of the [`eval()` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

```js
function addJavascript(script_url){
  fetch(script_url).then(r=>r.text()).then(eval)
}
```

---

So, to answer your actual question: You would use the `eval()` function to execute Javascript from a string. You should however, avoid doing so if at all possible, and instead use the method above.

```js
var javascript = "alert('hello, stack-o')";
eval(javascript);
```

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your quick reply.  In my case i dont have any url . The response javascript  is read from a js file in server and modified with some dynamic value .The new content is returned as a string in response.

Comment: Thanks for the direction.Let me check the options that i can go with url approach.

Comment: @philip In #1 you are saying that you're doing a call to the REST API. That means you are on the client side making an HTTP request by a URL. Do we understand it correctly?

Comment: yes , making a rest call using endpoint http://domain/download ,AP will read the js file from server and modify the content of the file .Then returning the string to client. Please note that we are not writing the new file in server.